# Gradient Text in Flutter

Tags: text, flutter, gradient

I was wondering if it is possible to create a gradient over text
Flutter. There is a [gist](https://gist.github.com/sir-boformer/3983478215f41c94a7c903542389809f) of text gradient using Dart's ui, but it is kinda long and I was hoping to be simpler.

Comment: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/gradient_widgets

Comment: Take look at ShaderMask. Probably it is most simple solution
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ShaderMask-class.html

Comment: check this link https://bestflutterpack.com/how-to-display-gradient-text-in-flutter/

Answer (score 126):

You can use `ShaderMask` for that task. In `ShaderMask`, you need to set the [`BlendMode`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/BlendMode-class.html) to `BlendMode.srcIn`, "src" means the widget to apply the gradient to (in this case `Text`), "in" means only show the part of the `Text` where it overlaps with the background which is the text itself (so the gradient doesn't get applied on the background):

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class GradientText extends StatelessWidget {
  const GradientText(
    this.text, {
    required this.gradient,
    this.style,
  });

  final String text;
  final TextStyle? style;
  final Gradient gradient;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ShaderMask(
      blendMode: BlendMode.srcIn,
      shaderCallback: (bounds) => gradient.createShader(
        Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, bounds.width, bounds.height),
      ),
      child: Text(text, style: style),
    );
  }
}
```

### Usage

```dart
GradientText(
  'Hello Flutter',
  style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 40),
  gradient: LinearGradient(colors: [
    Colors.blue.shade400,
    Colors.blue.shade900,
  ]),
),
```

[image]

### [Live Demo](https://dartpad.dev/?id=19df026ebdf79ba64f82d749d3ba11e7&null_safety=true)

Comment: you make my day

Comment: great and functional answer, thanks friend.
but on the web, I'm having some problems to that effect.

Comment: I had a better result with "BlendMode.dstIn" rather than "BlendMode.srcIn", but the overall solution works well, thanks!

Answer (score 68):

Taken from [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/eda03e2586b186ffcf8ea2d4424232710dbb7c81/packages/flutter/test/widgets/text_golden_test.dart), you can use Text's style painter.

Create the shader,

```
final Shader linearGradient = LinearGradient(
  colors: <Color>[Color(0xffDA44bb), Color(0xff8921aa)],
).createShader(Rect.fromLTWH(0.0, 0.0, 200.0, 70.0));
```

then use it in the TextStyle's foreground

```
  Text(
        'Hello Gradients!',
        style: new TextStyle(
            fontSize: 60.0,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            foreground: Paint()..shader = linearGradient),
      )
```

[image: text gradient in flutter]

[Source code](https://gist.github.com/bluemix/fac4434e1d047ca6bc2a9023bed9dd04)

Comment: Please note that this feature is available only in Flutter versions higher than the current 0.51.

Comment: The bounds are inaccurate this way

Comment: Since flutter 3.7.0, it doesn't seem to work anymore on iOS. Was a great solution before

Answer (score 10):

Use [simple_gradient_text](https://pub.dev/packages/simple_gradient_text) package and create `GradienText`

```
GradientText(
    'Gradient Text Example',
    style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 40.0,
    ),
    colors: [
        Colors.blue,
        Colors.red,
        Colors.teal,
    ],
),
```

[image: Flutter Gradient Text]

Answer (score 2):

First, we import Pkg

[Link For PKG](https://pub.dev/packages/simple_gradient_text)

#### Radial gradient

[image: Click here to see text Style IMAGE]

```
GradientText(
           'Gradient Text Example',
           style: TextStyle(
             fontSize: 40.0,
           ),
           gradientType: GradientType.radial,
           gradientDirection: GradientDirection.ttb,
           radius: 6,
           colors: [
             Color(0xff159DFF),
             Color(0xff002981),
           ],
         ),
```

#### Linear gradient

[image: Click here to See Text Style IMAGE]

```
GradientText(
           'Gradient Text Example',
           style: TextStyle(
             fontSize: 40.0,
           ),
           gradientType: GradientType.linear,
           gradientDirection: GradientDirection.ttb,
           radius: .4,
           colors: [
             Color(0xff159DFF),
             Color(0xff002981),
           ],
         ),
```