# Flutter 2: Gradient Text with TextPainter breaking in Column

Tags: flutter, text, gradient

I am encouterring problem with my personal GradientText which is made to do not use ShaderMask.

Here the device I use:

[image]

I call it like that:

```
Column(
  children: [
    GradientText(
      'Party Lopes',
      const LinearGradient(
        colors: <Color>[
          Color.fromARGB(255, 227, 82, 0),
          Color.fromARGB(255, 244, 176, 0)
        ],
        begin: Alignment.topLeft,
        end: Alignment.bottomRight,
      ),
      style: TextStyle(
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500
      ),
    ),
  ],
)
```

And here the code of my Widget:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class GradientText extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;
  final TextStyle style;
  final Gradient? gradient;
  final int? maxLine;

  const GradientText(
    this.text,
    {
      @required this.gradient,
      this.style = const TextStyle(),
      this.maxLine = 1,
      Key? key,
    }
    ) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final TextPainter _painter = TextPainter(
      maxLines: maxLine,
      textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
      text: TextSpan(
        text: text,
        style: style
      ),
    );
    _painter.layout();

    print(_painter.size);

    return CustomPaint(
      size: _painter.size,
      painter: _GradientTextPainter(
        text: text,
        style: style,
        gradient: gradient,
        maxLine: maxLine
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _GradientTextPainter extends CustomPainter {
  final Gradient? gradient;
  final String? text;
  final TextStyle? style;
  final int? maxLine;

  _GradientTextPainter({
    Listenable? repaint,
    @required this.text,
    @required this.style,
    @required this.gradient,
    @required this.maxLine,
  }) : super(repaint: repaint);

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final Paint _gradientShaderPaint = Paint()
      ..shader = gradient != null ?
      gradient!.createShader(
        Offset.zero & size
      ) :
      null;

    final TextPainter _textPainter = TextPainter(
        maxLines: maxLine,
        textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
        text: TextSpan(
          text: text!,
          style: TextStyle(
            foreground: _gradientShaderPaint,
            fontSize: style!.fontSize,
            fontWeight: style!.fontWeight,
            height: style!.height,
            decoration: style!.decoration,
            decorationColor: style!.decorationColor,
            decorationStyle: style!.decorationStyle,
            fontStyle: style!.fontStyle,
            letterSpacing: style!.letterSpacing,
            fontFamily: style!.fontFamily,
            locale: style!.locale,
            textBaseline: style!.textBaseline,
            wordSpacing: style!.wordSpacing,
          ),
        )
    );
    _textPainter.layout(
      minWidth: 0,
      maxWidth: size.width,
    );
    _textPainter.paint(
      canvas,
      Offset(
        (size.width - _textPainter.width) / 2,
        (size.height - _textPainter.height) / 2
      )
    );
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(_GradientTextPainter oldDelegate) {
    return gradient != oldDelegate.gradient || text != oldDelegate.text ||
    style != oldDelegate.style;
  }
}
```

And here it gives this result :

[image]

Whereas it should give this result:

[image]

So I don't understand why it doesn't display the entire text, and I don't understand why when I pass 'Party Lo' as a text parameter it displays it.

[image]

And also I don't understand why when I change the maxLines to 2 for example it place it under my first line whereas there is so much space already available

[image]

Can somebody please provide help fixing these problems ?

Here the result I am trying to have:

[image]

Comment: How did you call your column? Can you share the full code of your main widget where you use column with gradient text widget?

Comment: I call it in a Scaffold as the page was completly empty

Comment: In scaffold's body right?

Comment: Yes in a scaffold body

Comment: And the last question, which device do you use as an emulator/simulator?

Comment: Check out this link you will find your answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51686868/gradient-text-in-flutter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i simplified your `_GradientTextPainter` a little bit and also added optional `alignment` property to `GradientText` - if incoming size constraints are not bounded (either width or height is not set) then it takes the minimum intrinsic size to draw itself, otherwise  `alignment` is used to align `GradientText` within sized parent widget:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

class GradientText extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;
  final TextStyle style;
  final Gradient gradient;
  final int maxLines;
  final Alignment alignment;
  final String ellipsis;

  const GradientText(
    this.text,
    this.gradient,
    {
      this.style = const TextStyle(),
      this.maxLines = 1,
      this.alignment = Alignment.centerLeft,
      this.ellipsis = '\u2026',
      Key? key,
    }
  ) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (context, constraints) {
        final TextPainter textPainter = TextPainter(
          maxLines: maxLines,
          textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
          text: TextSpan(
            text: text,
            style: style,
          ),
          ellipsis: ellipsis,
        );
        textPainter.layout(
          maxWidth: constraints.maxWidth,
        );
        final bounded = constraints.hasBoundedHeight &&
            constraints.hasBoundedWidth;
        final size = bounded? constraints.biggest : textPainter.size;
        // print('constraints.biggest: ${constraints.biggest},
        // textPainter.size: ${textPainter.size}');
        // print('incoming constraints are ${bounded? "" : "NOT "}bounded,
        // using ${bounded? "constraint\'s" : "text"} size: $size');

        return CustomPaint(
          painter: _GradientTextPainter(
            text: text,
            style: style,
            gradient: gradient,
            textPainter: textPainter,
            alignment: alignment,
          ),
          size: size,
        );
      }
    );
  }
}

class _GradientTextPainter extends CustomPainter {
  final Gradient gradient;
  final String text;
  final TextStyle style;
  final TextPainter textPainter;
  final Alignment alignment;

  _GradientTextPainter({
    Listenable? repaint,
    required this.text,
    required this.style,
    required this.gradient,
    required this.textPainter,
    required this.alignment,
  }) : super(repaint: repaint);

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final textSpanRect = alignment.inscribe(
      textPainter.size,
      Offset.zero & size
    );
    // print('=== $size * $alignment => $textSpanRect');

    if (debugPaintSizeEnabled)
      debugPaintPadding(canvas, textSpanRect, textSpanRect.deflate(2));

    textPainter.text = TextSpan(
      text: text,
      style: style.copyWith(
        foreground: Paint()..shader = gradient.createShader(textSpanRect),
      ),
    );
    textPainter.layout(
      minWidth: 0,
      maxWidth: size.width,
    );
    textPainter.paint(canvas, textSpanRect.topLeft);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(_GradientTextPainter oldDelegate) {
    return gradient != oldDelegate.gradient || text != oldDelegate.text ||
    style != oldDelegate.style;
  }
}
```

Comment: It works but only with Expanded, when I remove it there is a RenderFlex overflowed by Infinity pixels

Comment: I have updated the question so you will see my current use of it. I have tried to change your SizedBox.expand() by SizedBox.shrink() but it doesn't works too.

Comment: yes but if I wrap it in a `SizedBox` it depends only of it so it will just be a pain to use it. Sometime I will not known the Size I need so I can't. What I would like, is to do the same GradientText with a ShaderMask but without the ShaderMask and I can't figure it out.

Comment: sorry I hadn't got the possibility to answer you before. Thank you for your help, it works great but I guess the only thing missing is textoverflow that isn't working when I put it in the textstyle. So if I set only one line a part of the text which overflow just isn't rendered.

Comment: add `ellipsis: '\u2026'` (or any other string you like) when creating `TextPainter` - i mean inside `final TextPainter textPainter = TextPainter(...`

Comment: Thank you it works perectly ! I'll look at it in more detail to understand all of what you made, it is insane !

Comment: sure, your welcome, i left two `print()`s to be more verbose what size the widget takes

Comment: Yes I have seen that from what I have read it came from the size which wasn't the correct one right ? By the way I'll just modify you response with the code I have modified (there is a if which doesn't work due to an uninitialized variable, and I commented prints)

Comment: what `if`? this one: `if (debugPaintSizeEnabled) debugPaintPadding(canvas, textSpanRect, textSpanRect.deflate(2));`?

Comment: Yes this one, I have sent the modification

Comment: `import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';` it is used for "visual debugging" - more https://flutter.dev/docs/testing/code-debugging#debug-flags-layout

Comment: oh ok thank you I don't know this package sorry :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238277/discussion-between-da2ny-and-pskink).