# Flutter web app built with --web-renderer=html does not work on Safari until one clicks "Allow WebGL in Web Workers"

Tags: flutter, safari, webgl, web-worker

When one builds a Flutter web app with

`flutter build web --release --web-renderer=html`

then the app does not load (blank screen) when one views it through Safari 16.4 on desktop. It works if one clicks on "Allow WebGL in Web Workers" in the Safari settings (Develop > Experimental Features > Allow WebGL in Web Workers).

Can anyone help me with what can be done to fix this with the html web renderer, please?

There is no problem on Chrome nor on an older version of Safari (for example 15.5). There is also no problem when one uses `--web-renderer=canvaskit`, but I can't use that because I need a faster initial load time.

Answer (score 0):

This was happening only when using color gradients in text using the code from here: [Gradient Text in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51686868/gradient-text-in-flutter). I removed the color gradients and now the app works.